# Scrapy xpath aria-select=false

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, khan-academy

I am trying to get the transcription info from some Khan Academy videos using scrapy.
For example: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-basics/basic-alg-foundations/alg-basics-negative-numbers/v/opposite-of-a-number

When I Tried to select the Transcript button through xpath `response.xpath('//div[contains(@role, "tablist")]/a').extract()` I only got the information about the tab has the `aria-selected="true"` which is the About section. I would need to use scrapy to change the `aria-selected` from false to true in the Transcript button and then retrieve the necessary information.

Could anyone please clarify how I would be able to accomplish this?

Much appreciated !

Comment: Do you mean the transcript text?

Comment: Yes ! The transcript text from the lessons

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your network inspect you can see that an AJAX request is being made to retrieve the transcript once the page loads:

[image]

In this case it's https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/videos/2Zk6u7Uk5ow/transcript?casing=camel&locale=en&lang=en 
It seems to use youtube video url id to create this api url. So you can recreate it really easily:

```
import json
import scrapy
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    #...
    transcript_url_template = 'https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/videos/{}/transcript?locale=en&lang=en'

    def parse(self, response):
        # find youtube id
        youtube_id = response.xpath("//meta[@property='og:video']/@content").re_first('v/(.+)')
        # create transcript API url using the youtube id
        url = self.transcript_url_template.format(youtube_id)
        # download the data and parse it
        yield Request(url, self.parse_transript)

    def parse_transcript(self, response):
        # convert json data to python dictionary
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        # parse your data!
```

Comment: I wonder what the "casing=camel" part of the URL is for - it gives exactly the same data with or without it...

Comment: @JannieGerber yeah, seems so. Could be a deprecated parameter or could only affect some fields that are not present in this particular example. Either way, it appears to be unnecessary for this example